# TEG (seebeck) to drive small brushless motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, fan, peltier

is it possible to drive a small (~ 24x30mm) brushless motor with a small (40x40m, ~0-3V) TEG module? I am trying to educate myself on brushless motor function and control but can't find much info on minimum required voltages for small RC motors and ESCs.

I have ordered the following ESC and motor and am pretty clueless about whether they will work or not haha:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01IEHX12E/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IEHX12E)
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07HRHCG58/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HRHCG58)

The backstory is I am on a mission to get my TEG driven wood stove fan (Ecofan Airmax model) to run silently. The brushed dc motors that they use produce an audible ticking as well as a high pitched tone that I believe results from the motor tick finding resonance with various parts of the cooling fins. This is all fairly quiet but my desk sits about 5 feet from a tiny wood stove and I find the sound very annoying. My idea is that replacing the stock motor (https://www.caframobrands.com/mrkca01bx.html) with a brushless one may solve this issue. I am a bit confused as to how most ESC throttles are set up, and in this application I really only need it to remain at "full throttle" all the time. I accordingly bought that ESC with a pre-wired potentiometer on it but if anyone has another suggestion I am all ears.

As is probably clear, I know very little about small electronics and welcome any and all input!

[edit]: I found the following spec sheet for the same size TEG module: https://www.europeanthermodynamics.com/products/datasheets/GM200-127-14-10-v2.pdf

Based on that (estimating hot side temps between 100-200 C, Tcold 50), I am estimating that the power output is likely in the range of ~ 0.5-5 watts at ~ 1-3 volts. The existing motor is definitely spinning the fan at lower temps than that but it's not really moving any significant amount of air at that point.

Comment: Depends on how much current your thermoelectric cell can provide and how much current the motor needs. Motors take a lot of current. You'll definitely have to boost the voltage up, too, but that's less of a problem.

Comment: 1) How much **power** will your TEG(s) generate? 2) How much **power** does the motor need? 3) It is only going to work if the power from 1) is the same or larger than the power from 2). Also watch ElectroBoom's video where he messes with Peltier elements: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xY06PT5JDE

Comment: based on this article it sounds like a small TEG like this may be producing in the range of 5W: https://makezine.com/projects/the-amazing-seebeck-generator/. I can measure this later on mine. But part of my question is that i can't find those minimum power specifications for either the motor or ESC and was hoping someone might have a ballpark idea. Note that these fans are turning pretty slowly, I believe maxing out at ~900 RPM.

Comment: Obviously the stock motor is working great (other than the noise) with the provided power, and the brushless one I ordered is the same size, I just don't know if they will have significantly different power requirements, or if the ESC will need some minimum amount of power just to function

Comment: A 5V bldc fan with a boost converter would very likely meer your need.